# OpenCV error: arm_neon.h unknown type name

Tags: c++, opencv, neon, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to write a Python wrapper for a C++ project that uses OpenCV (my C++ knowledge is very limited).
I installed OpenCV 4.5.0 using this link:

https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.5-on-jetson-nano.html

Then I managed to compile the project on the nano and create an .so file, which I then try to load with `cppyy`, but I'm getting a very long list of errors when I try to load one of the headers:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AlgoTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    cppyy.include('NewAlgoManager.h')
  File "/home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cppyy/__init__.py", line 245, in include
    raise ImportError('Failed to load header file "%s"%s' % (header, err.err))
ImportError: Failed to load header file "NewAlgoManager.h"
In file included from input_line_18:1:
In file included from ./include/NewAlgoManager.h:4:
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:52:
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:343:
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cv_cpu_dispatch.h:213:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:38:9: error: unknown type name '__Int8x8_t'
typedef __Int8x8_t int8x8_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:39:9: error: unknown type name '__Int16x4_t'
typedef __Int16x4_t int16x4_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:40:9: error: unknown type name '__Int32x2_t'
typedef __Int32x2_t int32x2_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:41:9: error: unknown type name '__Int64x1_t'
typedef __Int64x1_t int64x1_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:42:9: error: unknown type name '__Float16x4_t'
typedef __Float16x4_t float16x4_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__Float32x2_t'
typedef __Float32x2_t float32x2_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:44:9: error: unknown type name '__Poly8x8_t'
typedef __Poly8x8_t poly8x8_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:45:9: error: unknown type name '__Poly16x4_t'
typedef __Poly16x4_t poly16x4_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:46:9: error: unknown type name '__Uint8x8_t'
typedef __Uint8x8_t uint8x8_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:47:9: error: unknown type name '__Uint16x4_t'
typedef __Uint16x4_t uint16x4_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:48:9: error: unknown type name '__Uint32x2_t'
typedef __Uint32x2_t uint32x2_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:49:9: error: unknown type name '__Float64x1_t'
typedef __Float64x1_t float64x1_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:50:9: error: unknown type name '__Uint64x1_t'
typedef __Uint64x1_t uint64x1_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:51:9: error: unknown type name '__Int8x16_t'
typedef __Int8x16_t int8x16_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:52:9: error: unknown type name '__Int16x8_t'
typedef __Int16x8_t int16x8_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:53:9: error: unknown type name '__Int32x4_t'
typedef __Int32x4_t int32x4_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:54:9: error: unknown type name '__Int64x2_t'
typedef __Int64x2_t int64x2_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__Float16x8_t'
typedef __Float16x8_t float16x8_t;
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include/arm_neon.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__Float32x4_t'
typedef __Float32x4_t float32x4_t;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

I saw there's a flag `ENABLE_NEON=ON` that I can turn off while comiling OpenCV, but I understood that it's not recommended. Anyone got an idea what could be causing this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-error-arm-neon-h-unknown-type-name/10389

Comment: There's not enough info to be able to diagnose fully, but you need to work out why the Neon SIMD types aren't initialized. This looks like a compiler configuration issue - and may well be an opencv issue, with what compiler options it is using.
Jetson Nano is Armv8, so Neon should be available.